# Programmatically upload hosted images using CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

In a website that uses [CKEDITOR](http://ckeditor.com/) to post articles, how do I, as a content creator, upload an image hosted at a third party (e.g: "http://www.tizag.com/pics/htmlT/sunset.gif") by using CKEDITOR's inbuilt upload function?

Back story:
I work at this tutoring website, my job is to read a student's question, and quickly find appropriate answer and post it. Many times I take references from wikipedia,  copy-pasting works, but anyone can right click the equation-image, and "open in new tab" to see that it was hosted on wikipedia. Instead of manually downloading and uploading each equation, there must be a way to programatically and (if possible) asynchronously upload them all. I am unable to understand their code, I can't figure out the curl to upload the image. I am hoping for a general javascript code that uses CKEDITOR's functions from my browser's console to upload an image hosted at a third party website. CKEDITOR.version: 4.3.3

Note: I am not the programmer of my work website, so I cannot install add-ons in CKEDITOR's installation folder on the backend. I need a way that uses my browser's console.

Comment: If someone can please point me to the right direction, that would be perfection. Is there anyway to call upload functions of CKEDITOR from java-script console?

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins that will do that for you in CKeditor.

Visit [CKEDITOR BUILDER](http://ckeditor.com/builder) to add any of the plugins below.

First plugin is the **[Image](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image)** plugin. See the screenshot.

**You can upload an image via URL with this.**
[image]

The other plugin is the **[Media Embed plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/embed)**

**This one as well will do what you want.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am not the programmer of this website, I only work as tutor. I do not have access to their  CKEditor installation folder, so I cannot install these addons. They are not going to do this for me either. I am looking for a javascript function, that would pass the third party image's url into default upload function and return the final uploaded image's url. I was able to find that CKEDITOR.instances["answers"].getData() and setData() was the way to edit (rich) text in the answering box. There must be a similar function available to upload images too.

Comment: I have very clearly specified that I cannot install ad-dons from their backend, I don't own the website, I would not be asking this question if the answer was one google search away, I am only a content creator, I only have access to the javascript console!